# Flex & Java socket programming

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, servlets, flex4.5

I am new to Flex. Please can any one give Flex socket programming example both sides Flex and Java

I am trying objectoutputstream in java server side and java client side it work fine.

But in Flex I fail to read & write object in stream so please can any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Flex and Java is definitely possible.

I have [a Flex and Perl multiplayer card game](https://www.facebook.com/appcenter/video-preferans) (for desktop and mobile) and it works fine since 4 years already.

For my game I send gzipped JSON data using [writeUTF](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html) ActionScript method (I use [com.brokenfunction.json.encodeJson](https://github.com/mherkender/actionjson) for historical reasons, but you could just use native JSON function):

```
try {
        // send the length of string in bytes followed by the string
        _socket.writeUTF(encodeJson(obj, null, true, true));
        _socket.flush();
} catch(e:Error) {
        trace('fetch socket send: ' + e);
}
```

On the server side you first read the 2 bytes containing the data length.

Also you have to handle [Adobe socket policy](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/socket_policy_files.html) and can use [my open sourced Apache module written in C](https://code.google.com/p/mod-socket-policy/) for that (for easier start there is also [a Perl script](https://code.google.com/p/mod-socket-policy/source/browse/trunk/socket-policy.pl) included).

Comment: can u give me that game source code to ravularajesh90@gmail.com

Comment: No - and if you think that I have answered your question, please check the green tick.